# Get user from identityId

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-cognito

I saved one element in dynamodb using the id with `AWS.config.credentials.identityId` and restricting with `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}`

This generates a `us-east-1:14b37fe3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` record in dynamodb for a user with sub in cognito user pool: `20a3902b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Now, I need to create an trigger in dynamodb and retrieve some user attributes like name and email to generate a billing, how I can retrieve this info?

I have tried using this function:

```
response = boto3.client('cognito-idp').list_users(
        UserPoolId='us-east-1_rYoyNTF4V',
        AttributesToGet=[
            'email', 'name', 'middle_name'
        ],
        Filter='sub = "{sub}"'.format(sub=sub)
    )
```

But it's only works for the `20a3902b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` sub.

Comment: For a temporary fix I have added the user sub ```20a3902b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx``` on my Table in Dynamodb